# Run time error '5': while using global variables

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

i declared the global variable in the Module1 and when i was trying to use it in another module it is showing the runtime error '5':\invalid procedure call or argument. i was unable to find the problem please provied the solution for this problem
 Declaring global variable:

```
Function getFilePath() As String
 getFilePath = FilePath
 Set FilePath = "C:\quadyster\R3AgreementDetails"
End Function
```

Implementing of globalvariable:

```
Private Sub SendAgreement_Click()
 If (Not IsNull(Me.RequestFrom) And Not IsNull(Me.RequestReference)) Then
 Call AttachR3ServiceAgreement(Module1.FilePath, tripObjectFormation, "Agreement")
Me.AgreementDate = Now()

Else
 MsgBox "Please provide 'RequestFrom' and 'RequestReference' to proceed." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
            "Press Ok to continue.", vbOKOnly, "Alert!!!"
End If
End Sub
```

this is the calling function

```
Public Function AttachR3ServiceAgreement(FilePath As String, tripData As 
  tripDetails, requestType As String)
```

Here error is occured:
      Set objStream = objFSO.OpenTextFile(fileHTML, ForReading)

Comment: If it's a global why pass it as a parameter to your function? Or is it a different variable you're using as a global - Not very clear problem description

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error there: `Set` can only be used with objects.

```
Public FilePath As String
Function getFilePath() As String
  FilePath = "C:\quadyster\R3AgreementDetails"
  getFilePath = FilePath 
End Function

Private Sub SendAgreement_Click()
 If (Not IsNull(Me.RequestFrom) And Not IsNull(Me.RequestReference)) Then
 Call AttachR3ServiceAgreement(Module1.FilePath, tripObjectFormation, "Agreement")
Me.AgreementDate = Now()

Else
 MsgBox "Please provide 'RequestFrom' and 'RequestReference' to proceed." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
            "Press Ok to continue.", vbOKOnly, "Alert!!!"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: i inistalised the value for global variable in the function getFilePath() but while using the global variable it showing as empty string .